# Running from CLI I get this error: Uncaught ImagickException: improper image header, running from web I have no issues using PHP, why?

Tags: php, imagick

Can someone help me, I am trying to run a simple code to count PDF pages count with this code:

```
$pathToFile = 'book-97.pdf';
$img = new Imagick();
$img->readImage($pathToFile);
$totalPages = $img->getNumberImages();
echo $totalPages;
```

Running this code using browser I get **94**, running this code from CLI I get this error using command `php t.php`:

> Uncaught ImagickException: improper image header
> `/tmp/magick-279623pIzcdGAGVGh1' @ error/bmp.c/ReadBMPImage/966 in
> t.php:3

I have check version on both Browser and CLI and both versions of Magick are

> Version: ImageMagick 6.9.10-68 Q16 x86_64 2020-04-13
> https://imagemagick.org Copyright: © 1999-2019 ImageMagick Studio LLC
> License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php Features: Cipher
> DPC Modules OpenMP(3.1)  Delegates (built-in): bzlib freetype gslib
> jng jpeg lcms ltdl lzma openexr png ps tiff wmf x xml zlib

Can you give me some hits what is going on and why I can run this script with no problems from the browser, but I get this error running it from CLI?

UPDATE: When i run this command `convert book-97.pdf -format "%n\n" info: | head -n 1` I get this error

> convert: unable to access configure file `delegates.xml' @ warning/configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/677. convert: length and filesize do not match` /tmp/magick-11549ieKwhpyrnC8R1' @
> warning/bmp.c/ReadBMPImage/846. convert: length and filesize do not
> match `/tmp/magick-11549ieKwhpyrnC8R1' @ warning/bmp.c/ReadBMPImage/846. convert: improper image header` /tmp/magick-11549ieKwhpyrnC8R1' @ error/bmp.c/ReadBMPImage/966.
> convert: PDFDelegateFailed `[ghostscript library 9.25] -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 '-sDEVICE=bmpsep8' -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 '-r72x72' -dUseCIEColor  '-sOutputFile=/tmp/magick-11549ieKwhpyrnC8R%d' '-f/tmp/magick-11549BvI_xL9wmGky' '-f/tmp/magick-11549D-6RiAy13Nwe': (null)' @ error/pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/654. convert: no images defined` info:' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3235.

Comment: What was your CLI command?  Try `convert image.pdf -format "%n\n" info: | head -n 1`

Comment: my CLI command is `php t.php`

Comment: @fmw42, i added the information in the question

Comment: Post your input PDF file. Do you have Ghostscript installed? Does your ImageMagick policy.xml file permit reading of PDF files?